# Calling Azure AD protected Azure Function from Angular5 app

Tags: angular, azure, azure-functions, angular5

I am trying to call an Azure AD protected azure function api from an angular5 app. CORS is configured in Azure function and I am able to properly call this api when the API is made anonymous (proving CORS is configured correctly) . Now my Angular5 app is also Azure AD protected (using the same Azure AD app as the Azure function). While calling the Azure function,  I am passing the access token of the logged in user to the headers as bearer token. But my API calls fails with below error:

```
Failed to load https://login.windows.net/<tenantid value here>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https://<functionurl>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback&client_id=<clientid>&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=<some alphanumeric>&state=redir=/api/Projects/Country/IN: Redirect from 'https://login.windows.net/<tenanid>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https://<functionurl>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback&client_id=<clientid>&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=<some alphanumeric>&state=redir=/api/Projects/Country/IN' to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https://<functionurl>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback&client_id=<clientid>&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=<some alphanumeric>&state=redir=/api/Projects/Country/IN' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am using ng2-adal to login the user and get access tokens. Also, I have created an tokeninterceptor to put bearer tokens into all http requests.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public authSvc: AuthenticationService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authSvc.getCachedToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

**Update:**
The issue is resolved now. The thing I missed was to update the manifest of the Azure AD app with below settings (it is false by default):

```
“oauth2AllowImplicitFlow”: true
```